# Make UltiSnips perform XML encoding on tabstop text

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, filetype-xml

I'm writing an XML document where I frequently produce markup like this:

```
We can exit Terminal mode by pressing <keystroke>&lt;C-\&gt;&lt;C-n&gt;</keystroke>.
```

I'd like to define an UltiSnips snippet to help with producing `<keystroke>` tags like this.
Ideally, I'd be able to type (where `<tab>` expands the snippet, and `<C-j>` jumps to the next tabstop):

```
keystroke<tab><C-\><C-n><C-j>
```

and have it output:

```
<keystroke>&lt;C-\&gt;&lt;C-n&gt;</keystroke>
```

Is it possible to create a snippet for UltiSnips that behaves this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expression snippet it's possible to achieve this. Following snippet works almost ideally:

```
snippet "keystroke([^>]\S+)?" "Adds keystroke" r
<keystroke>`!p snip.rv = (match.group(1) or "").replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;")`</keystroke>$0
endsnippet
```

It works after you enter all the key sequences, for example: `keystroke<C-\><C-n>`<kbd>Tab</kbd> will result in:

```
<keystroke>&lt;C-\&gt;&lt;C-n&gt;</keystroke>
```

with the cursor position after `</keystroke>`

Comment: Edited the answer. Enclosed `match.group(1)` in `()` and added empty string as a fallback

Comment: This snippet works nicely, thanks. I wonder if it's also possible to do the substitution in a `post_expand` action?

Comment: I had to do it this way, because UltiSnips prevents and makes it very troublesome to edit current line, so anything after snippet was expanded makes it hard to change, mainly because this particular snippet is contained in just one line